# How can remove software from Ubuntu startup?

Tags: startup, startup-applications, startupmanager

When I start Ubuntu some software automatically starts with Ubuntu startup, for example Teamviewer. I don't want to start any software during startup except Ubuntu community software. Can Ubuntu have any startup manager software to optimize startup? Also how can I manage manually Ubuntu startup processes?